# Provide server side (PHP) data to AngularJS before serving to client

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm starting my **first project on angular**, which is a very **basic gallery** with tags.

**I'm moving my whole functional PHP code to Angular.**

So I have:

- an image folder with say 500 pics
- a JSON containing description, tags, etc. for each item

The thing I want is to **check the existence of each picture file and get its dimension before I display a thumbnail.**

In PHP an is_file() and getimagesize() is really fast on 500 pics, but **in angular I don't want to make a request to the server from client side foreach picture, or even once for all of them, it is loosing precious load time...**

I wanted to provide angular an object, if it was simple js I would have done something like:

```
    <script>
    var existingImagesStyles = "<?php echo $existingImagesStyles; ?>";
    </script>
```

where the var would contain the dimensions for the existing files only.
So I was going to arrange this to a more Angular friendly way until I found this post: [Passing User Data from PHP/HTML to AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635038/passing-user-data-from-php-html-to-angularjs) where it says to not try to use php in frontend :(

**What do you advise me ?**

And if it is fine to provide a `json_encoded` object through the main view template, is there a way to hide it to the user (cz within script tags it will show up in source code)?

Or maybe I should set the dimension of each picture in a PHP inline tag directly in my ng-repeat like `<... ng-repeat="(k, item) in items">...style="<?php ... ?>" ... </>`?

Comment: Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to return the metadata on the initial fetch and embed it in the SCRIPT element as an expression - then it can be accessed like a 'normal JavaScript object'. `var existingImagesStyles = <?php json_encode($the_metadata); ?>;` - note there is *no* quotes. Consume the object (via `existingImagesStyes`) in Angular. If you do it right you can use *the same* data-source. JSON is "close enough" to JavaScript for this to work; the default json_encode settings also prevent injection in a CDATA [SCRIPT element] section. Win-win.

Comment: this is exactly what I did, but is there no better way ?

Comment: This way is 'fine' - all other ways to avoid multiple requests use some variation of such. You could also return *all* the meta-data via an additional request, instead of one-request-per-image (which would also eliminate the speed issues most likely). Note that the 'reason' given in the linked post *only* applies to the SPA portion of Angular; not the initial request or Angular-per-request.

Comment: So if i want the page to load 500 thumbnails from the beginning i have to serve server side data from a <?php echo $var ?> in template. nothing more angularish? thank you.

Comment: Not at all. You could also make *one* secondary request - *the data returned in both cases should be identical*. It will only be stupidly slow if *making 500 requests*. The advantage of including it in the initial response is there is no secondary response required at all; disadvantages include alternate (but unified) transfer - remember *it should be the same metadata* - and lack of thumbnail-data (as a batch) cache-ability.

Comment: and what do u think of the answer of the link I provide please? concerning separate frontend-backend

Comment: I think it's fine, but should be taken in context.

Comment: I agree w/ u thanks for ur fast opinion and help :)

Comment: what you are doing is ok. to make is more angular way you can do one XHR after initializing angular to load the json asynchronously. It will not cause any wait or delay for user.